# Python3 script ends randomly in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, exit-code

I am new to Docker and facing some beginner misunderstandings in the usage/concepts of Docker.

How I start my built image:

```
docker run -d -p 7070:80 --name mov_container my_image
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN pip3 install pymysql

COPY src/ /var/www/html/
COPY Movement_Tracker.py /var/movtrack/

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
apachectl restart

EXPOSE 80
CMD python3 /var/movtrack/Movement_Tracker.py > flog.log
```

Is this a prober Dockerfile?

The "Movement_Tracker.py" seems to stop every second or third day. But the script is designed to run endlessly.

More precisely:

- **ps aux | grep python3** at host (where docker is installed) shows the python3 process.
- Inside the container (`exec -it...ps aux | grep python3`) shows NO python3 process.
- The task of the script is to write some sensor data to a database, that does not happen anymore. (As mentioned after 2 or 3 days)

My questions:

1. Do I have an anti pattern, because there is an apache service and a never-ending python3 script running?
2. Why is the python3 script still visible on the host and not in the container? But it is obviously not working anymore.
3. Is it allowed to have an apache/php and a python script running in a single container?
4. Why stops the python3 script randomly (assuming there is no occurrence of script error?)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ps aux` executed inside the container?

Comment: Apache wouldn't be running in this container, as Apache doesn't get started in the entrypoint, but rather in the build process.